# Intuitive proof for distributive property of dot product using $\overrightarrow{u}\cdot\overrightarrow{v} = u_{x}v_{x} + u_{y}v_{y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the intuitive way to think of the distributive property using $\overrightarrow{A}\cdot\overrightarrow{B} = AB\cos\theta$:
[image]

Then, this makes me wonder if it's possible to prove distributive property using the more general form for dot product: $\overrightarrow{u}\cdot\overrightarrow{v} = u_{x}v_{x} + u_{y}v_{y}$

Comment: You are reusing $\theta$ for the angle between$A$ and $R$, between  $A$ and $B$ and again for the angle between $A$ and $C$.  They are not necessarily the same.  The proof is not correct because of that.  Renaming the angles is not sufficient, you need to say something about how the angle between $A$ and $R$ relates to the angles with $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hi, thanks for pointing that out, I changed it! However, I believe that renaming the angle should be sufficient as I don't think that we need to know the relationship between the angles to be able to prove it. This is because we know $\overrightarrow{R} = \overrightarrow{B} + \overrightarrow{C}$, and thus, $\overrightarrow{A}\cdot\overrightarrow{R} = \overrightarrow{A}\cdot(\overrightarrow{B}+\overrightarrow{C})$

Comment: How do you go from the right side of the first line to the second?    You are claiming that $R \cos \theta=B \cos \alpha + C \cos \beta$ because of their projections on $A$.  I think that hides the coordinate approach you ask about.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for following up! I completely understand your proof below, thanks! However, I don't think my method itself is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler using the coordinate definition because it just comes down to the distributivity of real multiplication.  If you write $R_x=B_x+C_x$ and the same for $y$, then $A\cdot R=A_xR_x+A_yR_y=A_x(B_x+C_x)+A_y(B_y+C_y)$ and now use distributivity and associativity in the reals.

Comment: I feel like this method leans towards mathematical proof, instead of geometrical? Do you think if it's possible to visualize this proof?

Comment: Yes, it is mathematical.  What one can visualize is very personal, so I don't know.